# How to prevent a random post/entry to appear twice using this code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this function to redirect to a random post. I am trying to find a mechanism to prevent the same random post to appear twice in a row. Can anyone give a hint?

```
function sofa_view_random_post() {

    // make array of all posts IDs
    $q = get_posts('numberposts=-1');
    $array = array();
    foreach($q as $p) {
        $array[] = $p->ID;
    }

    // randomize array to get random post
    $k = array_rand($array);
    $v = $array[$k];
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $v ) ); exit;

}
```

I get all posts IDs first and put them to array. I randomize the array to get a value. But not sure how to prevent same value from being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the previous result in the session, and make sure you don't pick that one again:

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION['last_random_post'])) {
    $_SESSION['last_random_post'] = -1;
}

do {
    $k = array_rand( $array);
} while( $k == $_SESSION['last_random_post']);

$_SESSION['last_random_post'] = $k;
```

I'm not sure how this applies to wordpress specifically, but it should be easily adaptable:

For completeness, here is the function incorporating the above code:

```
function sofa_view_random_post() {

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['last_random_post'])) {
        $_SESSION['last_random_post'] = -1; // Or null, as long as its an invalid ID
    }

    // make array of all posts IDs
    $q = get_posts('numberposts=-1');
    $array = array();
    foreach($q as $p) {
        $array[] = $p->ID;
    }

    // randomize array to get random post
    do {
        $k = array_rand( $array);
    } while( $k == $_SESSION['last_random_post']);

    $_SESSION['last_random_post'] = $k;

    $v = $array[$k];
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $v ) ); exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Store the last used ID in the session data, and when constructing the list of possible posts, omit that post from the list.

Like this:

```
function sofa_view_random_post() {

    // Initialise last post value as NULL if missing    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['last_post'])) {
        $_SESSION['last_post'] = NULL;
    }

    // Make array of all posts IDs except last viewed
    $q = get_posts('numberposts=-1');
    $array = array();
    foreach ($q as $p) {
        if ($p->ID !== $_SESSION['last_post']) {
            // Only add this ID if it's not the last viewed post
            $array[] = $p->ID;
        }
    }

    // Get random post ID and store it in the session
    $k = array_rand($array);
    $_SESSION['last_post'] = $v = $array[$k];

    // Redirect user
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $v ) );
    exit;

}
```

Comment: This will make it so a post is shown once and only once - I think the OP only wants to make sure that no post is shown twice *in a row*.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion I made. I meant, a post cannot be displayed twice in a row when user request a random post.

Comment: @nickb You are correct. See edit above - I prefer this over yours as it doesn't build the full array and brute force the ID selection, rather just omit the last ID from the possible choices.

Comment: It's likely negligible, but I do like both approaches, so of course it gets +1. However, you could also form the array with `$array[$p-ID] = $p->ID;` and get rid of the `if()` inside the loop, and outside of the loop do a simple `unset( $array[ $_SESSION['last_post'] ]);`. My guess is that would be the most efficient / optimal algorithm.